Combinatorics Pigeon Hole Poker Game
Suppose I shuffle a standard 52 card deck deck and give you 25 cards at random from it. You are then tasked with making 5 poker hands from these cards such that each card is in exactly one hand. The goal is to make as many of the 5 hands as you can be a straight or better (straight, flush, full house, quads, straight flush, royal flush). What is the probability that you can only make K hands equal to a straight or better where $1\le K \le 5$?
I have not found a way where it is possible to only be able to make 3; each time I am either able to make 4 or 5. Is it even possible to only be able to make 3? Outside of just monte carlo, is there a way to solve this? With my own monte carlo, I've actually been able to make 5 most of the time.
Trivially, one can see why 2 is always guaranteed- there has to be at least 2 flushes by the pigeon hole principle.

I could be easily be mistaken.  In my opinion, this isn't the sort of problem that lends itself to any sort of elegant math analysis.
